# accsec dicts inside one list python

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, django-queryset

i have this dicts inside list :

```
myList = [
{
    'foo':12,
    'bar':14
},
{
    'foo':52,
    'bar':641
},
{
    'foo':6,
    'bar':84
}]
```

print(myList) =

```
[{'foo': 12, 'bar': 14}, {'foo': 52, 'bar': 641}, {'foo': 6, 'bar': 84}]
```

i want to access to all dict with key 'foo' only to get this ruslut :

```
[{'foo': 12}, {'foo': 52}, {'foo': 6}]
```

or

```
 [12, 52, 6]
```

i try `print(myList['foo'])` but i got erorr

Comment: What has this got to do with django, btw? Is this from a `Queryset.values(...)` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest are only the values:

```
foos = [d["foo"] for d in myList] 
print(foos)
```

For the dicts, you could use some clunky:

```
foo_singletons = [{"foo": d["foo"]} for d in myList] 
print(foo_singletons)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
myList = [
{
    'foo':12,
    'bar':14
},
{
    'foo':52,
    'bar':641
},
{
    'foo':6,
    'bar':84
}]

foo_lst = [dictionary['foo'] for dictionary in myList if 'foo' in dictionary.keys()]

print(foo_lst)
```

Output:

```
[12, 52, 6]
```